# Why Socat is sending back the input to client?

Tags: linux, netcat, socat

I am using this command

```
socat -lm -d -d TCP4-LISTEN:5555,reuseaddr,fork EXEC:/bin/myscript,chroot=/root/,su=root,pty,stderr
```

to start a server but when i send the i connect to it through netcat and send some input, it sends back input+output . Why is that ? I don't want my input back .

#### Terminal 1:

`socat -lm -d -d TCP4-LISTEN:5555,reuseaddr,fork EXEC:/bin/myscript,chroot=/root/,su=root,pty,stderr`

#### Terminal 2:

`root@vm:echo "AAAAAA" | nc localhost 5555`
`AAAAAA`[i don't want this to be coming back to me]
`output(AAAAAA)`

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate a little bit more, like paste netcat command you are using, and show what you mean by "it sends back input+output"?

Comment: Done! tell me if u need anything extra.

Comment: I believe you seeing your input is just a result of you specifying the `pty` option. How is this used, do you need the `pty` option?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist - Please can you create answer based on your comment ?

Comment: @IwanAucamp Created an answer out of my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input being echoed back to the client is a result of using the [`pty`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html#OPTION_PTY) option.

If there is no requirement for having `pty` the easiest solution would be to simply drop that from the command line.